# Click action on QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qlistwidget

I created a List widget and added some indexes (or items) on it with Designer (Shutdown).
Now I need to do something when I click on this item (index). But I can't understand how to do it.

```
connect(ui->listWidget,SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));

void MainWindow::on_listWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if(ui->listWidget->indexWidget(index) == QAbstractItemView::Shutdown) {
        command = "shutdown /s /t 7200";
    }
}
```

I get error `'Shutdown' is not a member of 'QListWidgetItem'`

The row

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
```

was created automatically when I added the click action.

Screenshot of my List

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do with `ui->listWidget->indexWidget(index) == QAbstractItemView::Shutdown`?

Comment: Oh, Sry my bad, forgot
Shutdown - element in list
I edit my question, u can see

So, i just want to do something when i chose this element in my list, foe example set some variable

Comment: Does not exist: QAbstractItemView::Shutdown

Comment: Can u tell me right way how to do it?

In which class my list elements stored?

For example buttons in dialog i can choose like that: QDialogButtonBox::Ok or QDialogButtonBox::Close

How to do it with elements in List?

Comment: What you want to do is to know when you click the shutdown item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the slot called itemClicked:

[image]

And then filter by the text:

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    if(item->text()=="Shutdown"){
        command = "shutdown /s /t 7200";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx, u rly help me ^^