# How to add a QAction to a QListWidget

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qlistwidget, qaction

I have the following code:

**roslaserscandoialog.h**

```
public:
    explicit ROSLaserScanDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ROSLaserScanDialog();
    QListWidgetItem *createItemFromAction(const QAction* action);

private slots:
    void on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);

private:
    Ui::ROSLaserScanDialog *ui;
    QAction *mAddMsgs;
    QAction *mDeleteMsgs;
```

**roslaserscandoialog.cpp**

```
ROSLaserScanDialog::ROSLaserScanDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ROSLaserScanDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->listWidget,SIGNAL(on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),this,SLOT(createItemFromAction(QListWidgetItem*)));

}


QListWidgetItem *ROSLaserScanDialog::createItemFromAction(const QAction *action)
{
    Q_ASSERT( action );
    QListWidgetItem *mAddMsgs = new QListWidgetItem();
    mAddMsgs->setText( action->text() );
    mAddMsgs->setToolTip( action->toolTip() );
    mAddMsgs->setIcon( action->icon() );
    // ...
    return mAddMsgs;
}

void ROSLaserScanDialog::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    mAddMsgs = new QAction(QIcon(":ros.png"), tr("Add New Message"), this);
    mDeleteMsgs = new QAction(QIcon(":remove_item.png"), tr("Remove Message"), this);
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379396/click-action-on-qlistwidget) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311241/qlistwidget-event-on-item-click). Very useful as I set up my project in a very similar way, but nothing happens when I try to click on the `QListWidget`.

I know that in order to trigger the action I have to go to the slot called `itemClicked` as I did on the above code provided. 
On the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#addItem-2) I was trying to apply what is advised but I don't know why nothing happens.

Please point to the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at console output, there should a warning about connect failing. If you look at your code, the reason should be pretty obvious. Consider

```
SLOT(createItemFromAction(QListWidgetItem*))
```

versus your method which isn't even a slot

```
QListWidgetItem *createItemFromAction(const QAction* action);
```

See the difference?

---

And then you have this slot:

```
void on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
```

which you are trying to use as a signal

```
SIGNAL(on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*))
```

That obviously won't work.

---

It's a bit unclear what you want to happen when an item is clicked, but maybe you just should call `createItemFromAction` directly from the `on_listWidget_itemClicked`.

Additionally, add debug print or use breakpoint to verify that the `on_listWidget_itemClicked` is actually called when you click an item. If not, then you are missing connecting the relevant signal from your list view, ie. `ui->setupUi(this);` does not have that connect (in other words you did not do the connection in the GUI Designer).

Comment: Thank you very much for reading the question :) That was exactly the problem. It works now. I had to call `createItemFromAction` directly from the `on_listWidget_itemClickedAlso`. I don't understand why someone down-voted the question  though. It took me a while to extract the most important part of the info from the code and try to pose the question in an understandable way.

Comment: You are very nice and thank you for your time in answering the question! :)

Comment: @Emanuele No problem. It takes a while and a bit of practice until you wrap your head around how the whole Qt GUI thing works. As a final piece of related advice, today you should not use `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros unless you really need to for some reason, but instead use the new syntax which takes function pointers (see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example) for an example).